# error on header information on redirect

Tags: php

When I call this function in my code I have this error. Do you have any idea ?

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/www//boutique/Admin/header_menu.php:173) in
>   /home/www/boutique/includes/OM/HTTP.php on line 33 Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0000  395512  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0738  1789400 include( '/home/www//boutique/includes/Apps/Tools/ImportData/Sites/Admin/Pages/Home/templates/import_process.php' ) .../index.php:31
4   0.0746  1792488 forward_static_call_array ( )   .../AppAbstract.php:111
5   0.0746  1792896 OM\OSCOM::redirect( )
6   0.0747  1793400 OM\HTTP::redirect( )
7   0.0747  1793560 header ( )

```
public static function redirect($url, $http_response_code = null) {

  if ((strstr($url, "\n") === false) && (strstr($url, "\r") === false)) {
    if ( strpos($url, '&amp;') !== false ) {
      $url = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $url);
    }

    header('Location: ' . $url, true, $http_response_code);
  }

  exit;
}
```

Comment: You cannot output anything before a `header(..)` redirect it will cause an error and redirect will fail. It says there you have the output at line 173 of `header_menu.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you can't use "header()" after the headers are sent...that means for example, when the PHP already send the headers to the HTTP server (and then this send the response to the user, but you get it I guess) you can't append anything else.

So, for example if you want to redirect to another page, you need to include this "redirect" before send any HTML to the user (or as said to the HTTP server)...

If you want another way to do this and you can't actually redirect before sending any HTML, then, use the same HTML for the redirect, how?, use the  redirect HTML tag or some javascript.